# Cannot Initialize a parameter of type 'struct Node * ' with an lvalue of type 'struct Node *'

Tags: c++

I still don't know what the problem on my code.

I just want to call the insertInEmpty and insertAtBegin from the linkedlist class to pass the pointer last and certain integers.

I am confused and need some help on how to correct this... I appreciate the help!! Thank you!!

```cpp
struct Node *last = nullptr;

 last = linkedlist::insertInEmpty(last,5);   <---- error on last parameter
 last = linkedlist::insertAtBegin(last,4);   <---- error on last parameter
```

linkedlist.h

```cpp
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

class linkedlist
{
    public:
        struct Node;

        static struct Node *insertInEmpty(struct Node *last, int new_data);

        static struct Node *insertAtBegin(struct Node *last, int new_data);

};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

linkedlist.cpp

```cpp
#include "linkedlist.h"

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *insertInEmpty(struct Node *last, int new_data)
{
   // if last is not null then list is not empty, so return
   if (last != nullptr)
   return last;

   // allocate memory for node
   struct Node *temp = new Node;

   // Assign the data.
   temp -> data = new_data;
   last = temp;

   // Create the link.
   last->next = last;

   return last;
}

//insert new node at the beginning of the list
struct Node *insertAtBegin(struct Node *last, int new_data)
{
   //if list is empty then add the node by calling insertInEmpty
   if (last == nullptr)
   return insertInEmpty(last, new_data);

   //else create a new node
   struct Node *temp = new Node;

   //set new data to node
   temp -> data = new_data;
   temp -> next = last -> next;
   last -> next = temp;

   return last;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the full error message. The error is not on the last parameter (which is an `int`)

Comment: Note that in C++ you don't have to (and should not) prefix every type mention with `struct`.

Comment: Side remark: Use `Node*`, not `struct Node*`

Comment: You define e.g. `insertInEmpty` as a static member function in the class `linkedlist`. But then you define a global and non-member function `insertInEmpty`. Besides that, what is the reason behind making the functions static?

Comment: Here is the error, sorry for not including it...
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'struct Node *' (aka 'linkedlist::Node *') with an lvalue of type 'struct Node *' (aka 'Node *')

Comment: The symbol `::Node` is very different from the symbol `::linkedlist::Node`. I think you need to take a couple of steps back, and start over with whatever text-book you have.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `struct Node;` in `linkedList` doesn't declare a member, but an inner struct.

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct Node` is an inner struct in `linkedlist`.
Either use `linkedlist::Node *last = nullptr;` or move it out of there.
Your cpp file should also use the `linkedlist::` scope for `Node` implementation, or you would get linkage issues.